# relative position in responsive webpage

Tags: css, responsive-design, position, css-position, responsive

How can I keep up element positioned stick to the above element in a responsive webpage?

For example I have a horizontal gallery of images that are reducing they dimension when the screen get smaller, so at the moment the footer that is supposed to stay directly below of that gallery keep moving depending on the size of the screen, leaving a variable ammount of white space in the middle.

I am trying to using "position" relative but I don't know how to make the position of the footer relative at the specific object that I want, in this case the gallery of pics.

Thanks

Comment: can you show your html and css? its hard to guess where your problem is

Comment: sorry i am new here and not sure how can show properly the code, however here is the link for what i am doing:https://www.dropbox.com/sh/1lmu82ymvkqww57/AABMj2Yzv0vXfTCmUrnQzrm_a?dl=0

Comment: so if you open the index, in the home page I am trying to fix the white space between the 4 pictures in the middle page and the grey area of the contact section

Comment: So basically the point is, I have some fluid images and the object at my aims is to stick the object at the bottom of this image in a way that when the images get smaller or bigger this object move in function of the dimension of this images.

Comment: At the moment when the images get smaller I get a empty space between the images and the object below, and when the images get bigger they become covered by the same object...

Comment: please let me know if the problem is not clear or i can do anything to explain myself more clearly